# c++ libssh - ssh_channel_read() keeps returning 0 and ssh_channel_is_open() returns false

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, libssh

This is the first time I am implementing ssh programmatically and I am baffled about why my code does not work -- to be more specific, **ssh_channel_read()** keeps returning 0 bytes read. I don't know what I am doing wrong! I have been following the API instructions step by step but I am obviously omitting something inadvertently.

I am trying to connect to my Pi with a  user name + password. Here is the complete code, you can just copy paste this and compile it with:

`g++ main.cpp -lssh -o myapp`

After the code, you can see the output I am getting. Please don't be harsh, like I said, this is the first time I am dealing with SSH:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <libssh/libsshpp.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
   int vbs                    = SSH_LOG_RARE;
   int timeout_ms             = 1000;
   ssh_session session        = ssh_new();

   ssh_channel channel;

   char        buffer[256];
   int         bytes_red;

   if (session == NULL)
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to create ssh session." << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
   }

   ssh_set_blocking(session, 1);

   std::cout << "Created SSH session..." << std::endl;

   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "192.168.1.5");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT_STR, "22");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "pi@192.168.1.5");
   ssh_options_set(session,SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &vbs);

   int con_result             = ssh_connect(session);
   int auth_result            = ssh_userauth_password(session, "pi", "1234");

   std::cout << "Connecton Result is: "   << con_result  << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Auth Result is: "        << auth_result << std::endl;

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Did we create the session successfully?
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   if (con_result != SSH_OK)
   {
      std::cout << "SSH connection failed. Error code is:  " << con_result << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return con_result;
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Did we authenticate?
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   if (auth_result != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
   {
      std::cout << "SSH authentication failed. Error code is:  " << auth_result << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return auth_result;
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Create a new ssh_channel
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   channel = ssh_channel_new(session);

   if (channel == NULL)
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to create SSH channel." << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return SSH_ERROR;
   }

   if (ssh_channel_is_open(channel))
      std::cout << "Channel is open" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "Channel is closed" << std::endl;

   while(!ssh_channel_is_eof(channel))
   {
      bytes_red = ssh_channel_read_timeout(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, timeout_ms);

//    if (bytes_red)
         std::cout << "Bytes read: " << bytes_red << std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "Exiting ..." << std::endl;

   ssh_channel_close(channel);
   ssh_channel_free(channel);
   ssh_free(session);

  return 0;
}
```

and here is the output I am getting when running it:

```
$./myapp
Created SSH session...
[2018/05/19 14:57:14.246759, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[2018/05/19 14:57:14.301270, 1] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
[2018/05/19 14:57:14.301321, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
[2018/05/19 14:57:14.301337, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 7.4 (70400)
Connecton Result is: 0
Auth Result is: 0
Channel is closed
[2018/05/19 14:57:14.669298, 1] ssh_packet_process:  Couldn't do anything with packet type 80
Bytes read: 0
Bytes read: 0
Bytes read: 0
Bytes read: 0
Bytes read: 0
^C
$
```

I can see the error, "Channel is closed" but why? What am I doing wrong?

After this, I also want to send data to the server and obviously get the feedback. From what I have read, **ssh_channel_write()** is the function to use.

I haven't dealt with SSH programmatically before and I am learning this as I write this.

All your help is very much appreciated.

**Update**

Thank to Jarra, I have solved this! Here is the final code that works!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <libssh/libsshpp.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
   int vbs                    = SSH_LOG_RARE;
   int timeout_ms             = 1000;
   ssh_session session = ssh_new();

   ssh_channel channel;

   char        buffer[256];
   int         bytes_red;

   if (session == NULL)
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to create ssh session." << std::endl;
      exit(-1);
   }

   ssh_set_blocking(session, 1);

   std::cout << "Created SSH session..." << std::endl;

   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "192.168.1.5");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT_STR, "22");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "pi@192.168.1.5");
   ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &vbs);

   int con_result             = ssh_connect(session);
   int auth_result            = ssh_userauth_password(session, "pi", "1234");

   std::cout << "Connecton Result is: "   << con_result  << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Auth Result is: "        << auth_result << std::endl;

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Did we create the session successfully?
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   if (con_result != SSH_OK)
   {
      std::cout << "SSH connection failed. Error code is:  " << con_result << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return con_result;
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Did we authenticate?
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   if (auth_result != SSH_AUTH_SUCCESS)
   {
      std::cout << "SSH authentication failed. Error code is:  " << auth_result << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return auth_result;
   }

   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   // Create a new ssh_channel
   ///////////////////////////////////////////
   channel = ssh_channel_new(session);

   if (channel == NULL)
   {
      std::cout << "Failed to create SSH channel." << std::endl;
      ssh_free(session);
      return SSH_ERROR;
   }

   ssh_channel_open_session(channel);

   if (ssh_channel_is_open(channel))
      std::cout << "Channel is open" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "Channel is closed" << std::endl;

   int rc = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "ls");


   while(!ssh_channel_is_eof(channel))
   {
      bytes_red = ssh_channel_read_timeout(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, timeout_ms);

//    if (bytes_red)
//       std::cout << "Bytes read: " << bytes_red << std::endl;

      std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
   }

   std::cout << "Exiting ..." << std::endl;

   ssh_channel_close(channel);
   ssh_channel_free(channel);
   ssh_free(session);

  return 0;
}
```

To compile: `g++ main.cpp -lssh -o myapp` and here is what you get when I run it:

```
./myapp
Created SSH session...
[2018/05/19 16:01:41.830861, 1] socket_callback_connected:  Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
[2018/05/19 16:01:41.884875, 1] ssh_client_connection_callback:  SSH server banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
[2018/05/19 16:01:41.884929, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  Analyzing banner: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Raspbian-10+deb9u1
[2018/05/19 16:01:41.884945, 1] ssh_analyze_banner:  We are talking to an OpenSSH client version: 7.4 (70400)
Connecton Result is: 0
Auth Result is: 0
[2018/05/19 16:01:42.258668, 1] ssh_packet_process:  Couldn't do anything with packet type 80
Channel is open
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Music
Pictures
Public
python_games
Templates
Videos
����s
Exiting ...
```

I just need to work on that last bit with the funny chars. This is straight out of my source code editor when I just got it to work, so the code isn't perfect.

Comment: There is actually another reason which might cause a similar issue, and I think it would be worth it to mention here. `ssh_channel_read` only reads on stdout OR stderr. So if `ssh_channel_read` returns zero, but `ssh_channel_is_eof` isn't true... then maybe there are bytes available to read on the stream you're not reading. You kinda have to read from both stream, if you want to be safe, as `ssh_channel_read` will stop monitoring stdout if output is available on stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh_channel_new` allocated the resources for a new channel. It does not open it.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you should then call an appropriate `ssh_channel_open_XXXX` function on that channel.

A simple example can be found here: https://github.com/substack/libssh/blob/c073979235eb0d0587ac9cb3c192e91e32d34b06/examples/exec.c

First `ssh_channel_open_session` is called to open a session (shell) channel, and then `ssh_channel_request_exec` is called to execute the `lsof` command.

How/when you will write to the channel depends on the type of channel you have opened. An example of writing to a session channel (after calling `cat > /dev/null` on the host to pipe written data to /dev/null) can be seen here: https://github.com/substack/libssh/blob/c073979235eb0d0587ac9cb3c192e91e32d34b06/examples/senddata.c

Comment: Thanks, my objective is to programmatically send commands to an ssh server and retrieve the output returned and then process it. It should not be interactive shell/keyboard mode. Pretty much like this - I would send: "Hello server, how are you", server returns "I am good thanks" which I will capture and do stuff if the server is feeling alright :) I will read those links. I confirmed that once I call `channel_open_session()`, the channel remains open but reading still returns 0. I will check out those links.

Comment: You'll have to execute a command before you get output. Thinking of session-style channels as basically giving you a programmatic shell on the remote system. If you execute `ls` you should get back a list of files in the current directory .etc.

Comment: It works!! Thank you, I will post my final / edited code that works and accept your answer.